# GSheet: Include multiple hyperlinks in 1 cell when using importrange?

Tags: google-sheets

I have two sheets (sheetA & sheetB).

In sheetA, there is a column for links. Some cells have multiple links. When I use import range, the hyperlink disappears. Please see these Google Sheets ([sheetA](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hEr3MQs04k60anhnvauY-ElBpcXI2s2gftSMOuKYJOU/edit#gid=0) & [sheetB](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XSz1yPP8iqH3RDP7LwGfLQdLLLA8KQKaR1wEIxqiTdc/edit#gid=0)) as a detailed example. Is it possible to include multple hyperlinks when using an import range? Any advice appreciated. Thanks.

| Customer | Device(s) | Links |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ken Le | iPhone XR | Apple Store (hyperlink working) |
| Ron Smith | Pixel 7 | Google Store (hyperlink working) |
| Pauline Lam | iPhone 13 and Pixel 8 Pro | Apple Store and Google Store (hyperlink not working) |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Possible Limitation:

I stumbled upon a post from [google community](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/203944251/importrange-function-not-importing-multiple-hyperlinks-from-a-single-cell?hl=en) with the same issue as yours and it seems that this is a possible limitation to the function `IMPORTRANGE` when importing a cell with multiple links.

### Suggestion:

You can try this `custom menu` that I created which triggers an Apps Script and copy the data from your `sheetA` to `sheetB` with the links and format

### Script:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Import Data', 'customImport')
      .addToUi();
}


function customImport() {
  var sourceUrl = "Insert sheetA URL here"
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(sourceUrl);
  var dest = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var range = source.getDataRange().getRichTextValues();
  dest.getRange(1, 1, range.length, range[0].length).setRichTextValues(range)

}
```

### Output:

[image]

### References:

[getRichTextValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getrichtextvalues)

[Custom Menus in Google Workspace](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus)